# How to include user message in facebook custom open graph story?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want to publish an open graph story with a user message from an Android app.
The open graph story appears in users news and activity log.
However, the user message is not visible. What am I doing wrong?


The app is defined as a games app.

The app has the publish_actions permission.

The user is a facebook test user.

I have defined a custom action "won" with "user messages" and "explicitly shared" enabled.

I have defined a corresponding custom object "medal".

I have the following code to publish the story:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("medal", "<url to medal html>");
params.putString("message", "test message");
params.putString("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");

Request postMedalRequest = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/twistwordcommunity:won",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("TWTEST-TAG", "Posting failed: " + error.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                Log.i("TWTEST-TAG", "Posted successfully");
            }
        }
    });
Request.executeBatchAsync(postMedalRequest);
```

And finally I have the following html for the medal object (verified using the open graph debugger):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:type" content="twistwordcommunity:medal"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Bonze level!"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Won bronze in TwistWord."/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<url to this medal html>"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<url to image>"/>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="523030476477949"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>New Medal! - Bronze!</p>
        <img src="<url to image>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you enable any of the capabilities (like user messages, tagging, explicitly sharing, etc), the action must be approved first before arbitrary users can take advantage of it. Unless the profile you're using is a developer on the app.

Comment: The profile I am using is a defined as Test User for the app. Shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Instead of using a Bundle, try creating an OpenGraphAction object, and set the properties using the setProperty method. Then use the newPostRequest method https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newPostRequest(Session,%20String,%20GraphObject,%20Callback)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it made no difference though. Strangely enough, the user messages suddenly started to appear - even though I made no changes to neither app settings in facebook nor to the code I posted above.